# Mathematic rule about square numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, square-numbers

sorry for every possibile grammatical mistake I may make, anyway, I’d like to ask you if this rule has been “discovered” before:
A square number is formed by the sum of the previous square number and the corresponsing odd number so:

25(**5th** square number)=16(previous square number)+9(**5th** odd number)

64(**8th** square number)=49(previous square number)+15(**8th** odd number)

4(**2nd** square number)=1(previous square number)+3(**2nd** odd number)

1(**first** square number)=1(because there’s no previous square number and 1 is the **first** odd number)

Eccetera eccetera.
Has this ever been discovered?

Comment: Follows trivially from $(n+1)^2-n^2=2n+1$.

Comment: You might be interested in [gnomons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnomon_(figure)#Building_figurate_numbers).

Comment: This is very well known. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1461779/sum-of-odd-numbers-make-squares, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136/why-are-the-differences-between-consecutive-squares-equal-to-the-sequence-of-odd, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639068/sum-of-odd-numbers-always-gives-a-perfect-square, etc., etc.

Comment: Good thing to observe - congratulations. That said, there are many duplicates of this question. Here's one:  [Direct Proof that $1 + 3 + 5 + \cdots+ (2n - 1) = n\cdot n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136237/direct-proof-that-1-3-5-cdots-2n-1-n-cdot-n)

Answer (score 1):

Let $x^2$ be the xth square number. The xth odd number is just 2x - 1, and the previous square is (x - 1)^2. Thus, you're showing that:

$$x^2 = (x - 1)^2 + 2x - 1$$
$$x^2 = x^2 - 2x + 1 + 2x - 1$$
$$x^2 = x^2$$